# php mysql get id of last insert row giving error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i want to get the id of last inserted row and i m using mysql_insert_id() function. but giving issue

here is my code :

```
if($i == 0)
{
    $query = "update events set e_did ='".$multi_event."' where eid = '".$display_id."'";
    mysqli_query($con,$query);
    file_put_contents('log.txt', mysql_insert_id(), FILE_APPEND);
}
else
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO events (start_date, end_date, text, rec_type, event_pid, event_length, e_did) VALUES ('".$row['start_date']."','".$row['end_date']."','".$row['text']."','".$row['rec_type']."','".$row['event_pid']."','".$row['event_length']."','".$multi_event."')";
    mysqli_query($con,$query);
    file_put_contents('log.txt', 'A'.mysql_insert_id().'A', FILE_APPEND);
}
```

now both time i m getting same id. what is the issue. is i m doing wrong something somewhere ?

Comment: have you any primary key auto increment in your table `events`?

Comment: id column is auto incremented

Comment: so it should works after insert query .it will not work after update query

Comment: why using mysql_insert_id() in update ?? you know the insert id right?

Comment: `mysqli_query` + `mysql_insert_id` = `"STOP, Don't Pass Go, and Pay $200";`

Comment: ok trying...removing that function from update....

Comment: even after removing mysql_insert_id() function from update in the insert query its giving update id value and not the id of new inserted row

Comment: Refer to the answers given below. @Chintan_chiku - The "upvoted" ones. ;-)

Comment: Just to say for the following users it says on the php page that `mysqli_insert_id` returns a `ID` for `INSERT` and `UPDATE`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the mysqli functions, you must use [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php). You can't mix ext/mysql and ext/mysqli.

Also, UPDATE does not generate a new auto-increment id. You should call mysqli_insert_id() after INSERT, but not UPDATE.

Comment: UPDATE can be coaxed into setting the auto-increment id, though :)

Comment: @Jack, Yes, fair enough, but UPDATE does not advance the auto-increment columns in the way the OP was using it.

Answer (score 4):

`mysqli_insert_id()` only returns an `id` for `INSERT` queries. An `update` query will **NOT** return an id, because by definition you must already have a row in the database for it be getting updated.

Answer (score 2):

With `UPDATE`, you are editing records, not adding ones. So no *new* IDs are generated. You can only use `mysql_insert_id` on `INSERT`.

**Note:** `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and won't be supported in future versions. You should be using either [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).